# How does prove the following: if $a,b$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}_+$, then $a+b$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}_+$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I am trying to prove **Problem 5(a)**, in **Section 4** of **Munkres' General Topology**. He gives a hint that says:

Show that given $a\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, the set $X=\{x| x\in\mathbb{R} \,\,\textrm{and}\,\, a+x\in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$ is inductive.

I can show that the set $X$ is indeed inductive but how does one go from there to showing that $a+b\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.  It seems like he is asking us to build a set of $b$'s, if I am not wrong, and says that this set is inductive. I think I am missing a logical link.

Comment: I edited the tags because the question has nothing to do with topology.

Comment: Well, if $0 \in X$ then by induction $\mathbb Z_+\subset X$ and for every $b\in \mathbb Z_+$ then $b\in X$ and $a + b \in \mathbb Z_+$.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $a\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. Use mathematical induction on $b$. If $b=1$, then since $X$ is inductive, by definition it contains $1$, so $a+1\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, and the assertion holds.
Assume the assertion holds for some $b\geq 1$. Then $a+b\in X$, and since $X$ is inductive, also $a+b+1\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, so the assertion holds for $b+1$ as well.

Comment: Wait, did you mix-up X's and $\mathbb{Z}_+$'s?

Comment: Yes, I did. Fixed it.

Comment: I am still confused, your answer just proves that X is inductive - how does one go from there to understanding that (i) $b \in\mathbb{Z}_+$? and (ii) the question itself??.

Comment: my comment proves nothing. My answer, however, proves that if $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ then $a+b\in \mathbb{Z}_+$. It does so by invoking the principle of mathematical induction. I am not *proving* that $X$ is inductive. I am *using* it.

Comment: Thats exactly the thing - how do we know that $b\in\mathbb{Z}_+$? We only know that $b\in X$ an inductive subset of real numbers.

Comment: "how do we know that b∈Z+? "  Um, that's the premise of the statement we are trying to proof.  We are *given* that $a,b \in \mathbb Z_+$.  We construct $X$. We prove $X$ is inductive.  That means that $Z_+ \subset X$.  *THEREFORE* $b$ which we were *GIVEN* is in $\mathbb Z+$ is in $X$.  ANd by definition of $X$ as $b \in X$ (which we were *not* given but which we concluded) the $a+b \in \mathbb Z+$.

Comment: " We only know that b∈X"  We *don't* know that $b \in X$.  We only know that $b\in \mathbb Z_+$. That is what we are *given*.  But if $b = 1$ then $1 \in X$, and if $b=k \in X$ because $X$ is inductive $k + 1\in X$.  Therefore for all $b \in \mathbb  Z_+$ we have *proven* that $b \in X$ therefor for all $b \in \mathbb Z_+$ then $a + b\in \mathbb Z_+$.

Answer (score 0):

Well $a\in \mathbb Z_+$.  $X = \{x\in \mathbb R| a+x \in \mathbb Z_+\}$.

So $a + b\in \mathbb Z_+ \iff b \in X$. [*]

$X$ is an inductive set so $\mathbb Z_+\subset X$.

So.....  If $a, b \in \mathbb Z_+$ then $b \in \mathbb Z_+ \subset X$ so $b \in X$.  And therefore, by definition of X,   $a+b \in \mathbb Z+$.

.......

> I think I am missing a logical link.

I can only surmise that [*] somehow escaped you.

---

This *assumes*  that you have taken the books hint and have *already* shown that $X$ is inductive.

If you *haven't* well here's the outline:

Show that $1\in X$.  That is, show that if $a+1 \in \mathbb Z_+$.  (Bearing in mind that you *do* know $a \in \mathbb Z_+$.  This follows as $\mathbb Z_+$ itself is inductive.)

Prove that if $k\in X$ then $k+1\in X$. That is show that if $a+k \in \mathbb Z_+$ then $a+(k+1) \in \mathbb Z$.  (Bearing in mind that $a+(k+1) = (a+k) + 1$ and ..... $\mathbb Z_+$ itself is inductive....)

Comment: Aaah, thank you so much! Doh - moment for me! 

One quick question: how does one know this -- $X$ is an inductive set so $\mathbb{Z}_+ \subset X$?

Comment: Well, *THAT* is the heart of the proof.  You *claimed* you had proven $X$ was inductive.

Comment: Here's a hint to get you started.  If $a\in \mathbb Z_+$ then the successor of $a$ which is $a+1$ must be in $\mathbb Z_+$.  But that means $1 \in X$ ($a+1 \in \mathbb Z_+$).  And for any natural number $k\in X$ so that $a+k \in \mathbb Z_+$, then the successor of $a+k$ which is $(a+k) + 1 = a+(k+1) \in \mathbb Z_+$ so $k+1 \in X$ (by definition) and ... well, I guess that was more than getting you started.

Comment: Sweet, thank you so much!